# PowerShell command to support "Management services" in azuren portal

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to get the "operational logs" information contained in the "Management Services" of azure portal through PowerShell scipt. 
I can see it manually as, to which azure resource has been created and when.
I want to get the same information through PowerShell script.

Kindly suggest if it can be achievable in Powershell also, which commands help in achieving that.
FYI: Get-AzureResourceGroupInfo was not helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping you can call the REST API using PowerShell, you can get some help from here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715318.aspx - I'm assuming this is the information you're looking for.

This link helps you authenticate and make REST based calls from PowerShell
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/17/using-the-windows-azure-rest-apis-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 0):

hope given link will help you .

https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/operational-insights/operational-insights-analyze-data-azure.md